# Php url parameter error

Tags: php

I am getting error.

```
url.com/test.php?id=123&id2=456
```

This is my get.php

```
<?php

$id = $_GET['id'];
$id2 = $_GET['id2'];

?>
```

I am getting this error for 2nd parameter

instead of `&` url getting `&amp;`

Error

```
[23-Feb-2017 03:45:00 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: id2 in /home/xxxx/public_html/url.com/get.php on line 4
```

Comment: you url_encode() and url_decode() function for this

Comment: example please sir

Comment: search in google. you will find example

Comment: [Read How to ask on Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting a query

Answer (score 1):

```
  try this..
   url.com/test.php?id=" . urlencode($id) . "&id2=" . urlencode($id2);

 Decode:

  $id= urldecode($_GET['id']);
  $id2= urldecode($_GET['id2']);
```

Comment: header("Location: get.php?fbid=".urlencode($id)."&fname=".urlencode($id2)."");   Not working still I am getting error.

Comment: error is in & char. second parameter is not getting

Comment: @vience try this code i personaly test hope it should work -
$id=2;
$test=3;
<a href='./test.php?id=<?php echo urlencode($id); ?>&test1=<?php echo urlencode($test); ?>'>test</a>

test.php
<?php 
echo $id= urldecode($_GET['id']);
 echo $test= urldecode($_GET['test1']);
?>